# Intel Phi Coprocessing for Desktop PC

Tags: cpu, computer-building, computer-architecture

My question is, if I want really take advantage of all the novel advances for data-spec'd computing that are available right now, i.e.: Xeon Phi (and upcoming Knights Mill), 3dx point ssds, ect, Can someone explain the compatibility issues I may want to address if I want to add co-processors in my build?

Some Xeon Phi's need Linux OS if I'm not mistaken, but is the compatibility checklist terribly long? What do I mean? For example: Some Xeon Phi builds I saw used 2 power supplies. Is that always warranted? Also, knowing the theoretical/practical/realized benefits of having 2-3 coprocessors would be nice.

The answer doesn't have to address **every little thing** but maybe cover the most crucial.

Comment: The computer building tag is for help diagnosing a computer you have built or are in the process of building. What to buy could potentially be asked at  [hardwarerecs.se] but first check their help centre and read their [quality guidelines](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/206/1) as a large portion of your current question would be off topic there.

Comment: @mokubai post has been narrowed, please advise.